# Custom toolbar button for Pycharm IDE to show console and pending-changes window?

Tags: pycharm, toolbar

My web searches ([01](https://www.google.com.vn/?ion=1&espv=2#newwindow=1&q=pycharm%20create%20custom%20button%20to%20show%20console%20window) and [02](https://www.google.com.vn/#newwindow=1&q=pycharm%20create%20custom%20button%20to%20show%20pending%20changes&rct=j)) lead me to to [Menu & Toolbars Configuring](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/configuring-menus-and-toolbars.html) guide on JetBrains.

Though I can't find a way to add `Terminal` and `Version Control` command from **View - Tool Windows** into **Navigation Bar Toolbar**. More details is as attached snapshot #1.

(snapshot) *Navigation Bar Toolbar*

[image]

(snapshot) *Tool Windows*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As discussed on PyCharm issue tracker i.e. Jetbrains ticket [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO9ZF.png) we have the button at

```
... Left corner at the bottom.
Terminal and Version Controls tabs are already there` ...
```

[image]